# JQuery select a variable by passing a text string of its name

Tags: jquery

I'd like to use a JQuery selector to return a variable by passing a text string of the variable name:

ex.

```
var test = "xxx";
```

I'm thinking I could do something like this, but it won't work:

```
  alert($("#test"));
```

Edit:  People are getting confused.  Think of it as a reflective way to get the contents of var test.  Preferrably with a JQuery selector, but I'll take any way one can come up with it..

Comment: and `alert(test)` won't work because...?

Comment: because I want to use a string of the variable name.  not possible?

Comment: I think you want to use that string to build a selector, correct?

Comment: I answered based on the understanding that you want the string "test" from the variable `test`. Am I correct?

Comment: I answered wrong.  I have a string name "test", and I wanted to return the variable of that name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This should work for you.  You have to use the variable outside the string quotes like this.  You could replace the `#` with a `.` if you want to use a style selector vs an ID selector.

```
var test = "xxx";
alert($("#" + test));
```

If the field is something like `<input name="xxx" .../>`, you would have to use something like the following:

```
var test = "xxx";
alert($("[name=" + test + "]"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what your end target is, but I use the following method a lot when I need one thing to interact with another...

```
<a href='whatever.html' rel='#targetElem' class='loadable'>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.loadable').live('click',function(){  //when a element with the class of loadable is clicked
    $($(this).attr('rel')).load($(this).attr('href')); //load the contents of it's href URL into the element specified in it's rel attribute
    return(false); // stop processing the link;
 });
});

</script>
```

I tell the element what the target of the action will be using the rel attribute...

to get at variables try this  (window is a javascript built-in array of global variables...)

```
var i=2;

var test='i';
document.write('got ' + window[test]);
```

Comment: I changed your bottom suggestion to get it.  Awesome!  alert(window["test"]); works for my example above (IE8, FF, Chrome)

Comment: +1: innovative use of the window array. but dont recommend that anywhere :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are asking is best done with JavaScript objects, e.g.:

```
var obj = { test: "xxx" };
for(key in obj) {
    alert(key);  // "test"  
    alert(obj.key); // "xxx"  
}
```

You can do something like this, though I really don't see the point:

```
var obj = { foo: "xxx" };
for(key in obj) {
    alert($("#" + key).length); // 1   
}

<input id="foo"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/J4hC8/

Comment: helpful.  yes this is an alternate, but I'm trying to do it without an array

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is

```
alert($("#" + test));
```

Comment: That would get him the DOM element with the ID of the string held by test, but not the variable equivalent to the string held by test. he's trying to do a variable-variable as in echo $$test

Answer (score 0):

```
var test = "#xxx";
alert($(test));
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
var test = "xxx";
alert($("#" + test));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe you are looking for [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) function.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here is the solution. As stated by igor milla, you should use eval().

```js
var test = "xxx";
alert(eval("test"));
```